# Joining XMPP MUC Room without invite - ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, multiuserchat

For persistent XMPP rooms, what is the way to make a client join back the room again if he / she has disconnected once? During testing, I find that simply sending back the presence stanza to the said room's JID does not make the client be available in the room again. Does re-entering a room happen only when a user has received an invite (and thus, in our case, if the user disconnects once, the user would need another invite to join the room?)?

If that is the case, then what is the best way to implement the auto-generation of such invites for original room participants who are reconnecting?

Thanks.

Comment: Without invitation I don't think it's possible but you can setup a listener and invite the leaving user back into the room.

Comment: Thanks @MoatezBouhdid - tried sending the invite manually back too but the leaving user just wouldnt join! :-(

Comment: Was able to get the user to rejoin without the invite - just had to re-join at the right place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way it's to use **pubsub** feature and relative MultiUserChat **bookmarks**.
You can develop a custom bookmarks manager if you need something declined on your special needs.

Do you need the following steps:

1) When create a persistent groupchat, bookmark the groupchat after first join. (=> save on db groupchat name and password)

2) When recive an invite, bookmark the groupchat after the first join (=> save on db groupchat name and password)

3) On login / reconnect retrive bookmarks list

4) Foreach bookmark -> join (and assign listeners and so on)

5) Provide a delete bookmark condition (based on timestamp, session, explicit request and so on).

[Official specifications](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0048.html)

Comment: Thanks very much @MrPk - yes am trying to achieve the same. It is # 4 in your steps that the join fails. Even if I send a new invite to the said user, he / she cannot seem to join back the room from his / her locally saved bookmarks (which contain nothing but a list of the earlier joined rooms' JIDs (as am not storing pwds)).

Comment: You don't need really to send again an invitation, in theory you can force the join just as a succeffull accept of an invitation request. Of course check out if the MUC has a password (if has, you can't join without insert it again) ad room configuration looking for unusual combos of params. I use this way based on Openfire + Smack API but it's not implementation dependant

Comment: Well - it worked - I was putting in the force re-joining post the app launch instead of post authentication! Thanks much for the inputs...

Answer (score 0):

There is a [proposed XEP](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/) and it's implemented in latest ejabberd which supports subscriptions. It expose MUC rooms as pubsub nodes to introduce the concept of MUC rooms subscribers.

Comment: Thanks @Sabbir ... yes I've been playing around with the new MUC/Sub module but facing the same problem there too... unless I can get a room participant to rejoin the room, I cant find a mechanism to leverage subscriptions. Not sure if you'd have any further ideas...?

Comment: Found the solution - I was putting in the rejoin at the wrong place!